# Google Calendar as default handler of webcal protocol for iCal/ICS files

Tags: default-programs, google-calendar

I would like for Google Calendar to open URIs with the [Webcal (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) scheme (delivering ICS files), similar to how Gmail can be set to be the default handler for `mailto:` links.

More specifically, I would like for Google Calendar to import them to my primary calendar. (You can manually import an ICS file in Google Calendar by clicking the small arrow next to Other calendars,  choosing Import calendar from the drop-down list, navigating to the .ICS file, and choosing Import.)

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm hoping somebody will have a great idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Chromium

The chromium browser offers this option when you first log in to Google Calendar:

[image: Google Calendar in Chromium browser offers to handle webcal protocols]

If you have accidentally answered with `No` on this question, you can press the `Wrench` toolbar button and go to `Settings`. Click `Show advanced settings`, find `Content settings...` (just after Privacy header) and find the `Manage handlers` button. Click the `X` next to the ignored protocol you wish to delete. Alternatively, you can type in `protocol handlers` search box in Chromium settings.See the screenshot below.

[image: Undo ignore protocol handler in Chromium browser]

## Firefox

I found this [post on stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28430) which explains how to achieve the same thing in Firefox, <s>but this doesn't work for me on firefox 12 and 15:</s> this works for me if I disable the Never save history option (Private browsing mode):

> Go to Google Calendar's site and press `Ctrl+Shift+K`.
>
> Paste this after the > sign:
>
> `navigator.registerProtocolHandler("webcal","https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=%s","Google Calendar");`
>
> Press the enter key and click the `Add application` button which should appear below the toolbar.

[image: Firefox console]

[image: Firefox accept protocol hanlder]

You may need to toggle the `gecko.handlerService.allowRegisterFromDifferentHost` option in `about:config` to `true` before trying this (if google redirects you to a local google domain). Remember to return it to false after calling the registerProtocolHandler function because malicious sites may exploit this. See details [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Gecko.handlerService.allowRegisterFromDifferentHost).

Comment: Personally, I'm looking for the option for Chrome/Chromium. In case one did not react properly on first log-in, are there options open?

Comment: Yes, you can delete an ignored protocol handler. See my edited answer!

Comment: I found that I need to put `javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler("webcal","https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=%s","Google Calendar");` in the location bar in Google Chrome to get it to work.

Comment: I tried the Firefox solution but when clicking on a .ics file i get the pop up to store or open with gedit (as it's a VCS/ICS file) any tip on this?
btw http://superuser.com/a/442494/216033 mention a similar solution.

Comment: here a test ics (found it during my googling for a solutions) https://calendar-a-googleproductforums-com.googlegroups.com/attach/7bad8a76823debf0/calendar.ics?gda=m79upEYAAADgd9X9TXGCeZNRK36EXdn_D0WnDAP69ONCu5OLSO1tySbt0-9EzVemPZiSquJtCwdx40jamwa1UURqDcgHarKEE-Ea7GxYMt0t6nY0uV5FIQ&part=4

Comment: This doesn't work in newer versions of Chrome (see peonicles's answer).

Comment: Not working in chrome...

Answer (score 16):

In newer versions of Chromium/Chrome, you need to login to google calendar and click the overlapped diamond icon in the address bar.

[image: Screenshot]

Select "Use Google Calendar", then click done. This will register google calendar as a handler for webcal links.

Note:

You may need to set Chromium to allow sites to become default protocol handlers. You can do so via :

1. Advanced settings -> Privacy, Content Settings -> Handlers
2. Select "Allow sites to ask to become default handlers for protocols"

Comment: Not working in chrome...

Answer (score 4):

As of Jan 2020 I managed to **solve** this for **Firefox** by doing the following:

- *about:config* - switch *dom.registerContentHandler.enabled* to *true*;
- open *Google calendar*;
- press *Ctrl+Shift+K* to open console;
- copy the following code, paste it into the console and press Enter:

  javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("webcal","https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=%s","Google Calendar");

After these steps, you should see a window-width stripe under the address bar asking you if you want to set Google calendar as a default webcal handler.

Before all that, I tried to use the master Yoda's solution but it didn't work - anyway, cheers, it inspired me to look closer at the about:config entries and to discover this method.

Answer (score 1):

Since I came across the same question as the OP and things have changed since the accepted answer was posted, I thought I'd share my findings. The following instructions are mainly for Firefox, but apart from little differences they **should** work in Chrome, too.

### [2019-03-08] Update: reflect new Firefox behavior

Because using

```
    javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("webcal","https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=%s","Google Calendar");
```

at Firefox's console results in a

> SecurityError: Permission denied to add https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=%s as a protocol handler

nowadays, here's the new way to still "make it happen":

1. Navigate to `about:config`, confirming the risk by clicking the button.
2. Type `webcal`, filtering the list to items of type `gecko.handlerService.schemes.webcal.[...]`.
3. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button at the right of your chosen `[...].name` item (since **30 Boxes** was [abandoned with Firefox 67](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1252831), I opted for `[...].0.name`)
4. Type in your desired name, e. g. `Google Calendar` and click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
5. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button of your corresponding `[...].uriTemplate` item, i. e. the one just below your edited one.
6. Paste the URL `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r?cid=%s` and click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
7. Go to Firefox's options for associated applications by consecutively clicking <kbd>≡</kbd>, <kbd>⚙ Options</kbd>, <kbd>⚙ General</kbd> menu options and then scrolling down to the **`Applications`** paragraph.
8. Search the list for `webcal` by either typing it into the search box just above the list or via scrolling.
9. Click the drop-down at the entry's right half and select `Use Google Calendar` (or whatever name you chose at instruction #4).

Test calendars: https://www.webcal.fi/en/calendars.php

HTH. If not, just leave a comment below.

Comment: Followed all steps but still doesn't work for me on FF 50.1.0 / Ubuntu x64. All is as you said but ics still invokes dialog with content handling (save or run app). I've tried `navigator.registerContentHandler` method but still no results, URI/gcal is not being registered for mime type: `text/calendar`

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that either Google or Mozilla changed something and it therefore doesn't work at the moment. Though, you can still manually add an entry for `gecko.handlerService.schemes.webcal.X.name` and `gecko.handlerService.schemes.webcal.X.uriTemplate` (where X is a number higher than the highest current one) within the `about:config` URL. afterwards, you can continue with instruction #5.

Comment: I just tried this on latest Google Chrome with no luck.  I could get the handler to register, but no luck making an ICS file load into Google Cal with that handler registered.

Comment: @CraigLambie First off, it's pretty sad finding my answer being "`-1`ed" by unhappy Chrome users. Secondly, I never said "instructions work in Chrome, too". Instead, I **clearly** stated: "_apart from little differences_ they _should_ work in Chrome"! Lastly, since I won't ever use Chrome, I simply don't care how it handles webcal links - for Firefox it works and that was the reason behind this whole answer right from the start - for Chromium-based solutions, see answers of @peonicles or @jeremija and ask them for further Chrome fixes.