# Chrome "open-with" for local webcal:// .ics file

Tags: google-chrome, calendar

I've set up chrome to [handle webcal files](https://askubuntu.com/a/451882/196639), but it still just downloads them if people haven't used "webcal://" in the url. This doesn't matter to me so much because I figure I can just click on the downloaded file and have chrome open it for me. It almost works, setting up an "open-with" option in KDE:

```
google-chrome "webcal://%u"

#becomes
google-chrome "webcal:///home/blah/file.ics"
```

This does open up google calendar, but then I get the message *"**Sorry** This email address isn't associated with an active Google Calendar account: webcal:///home/blah/file.ics. Please check the email address and try again."*

Strange. It's not an email address. Is it expecting me to give it a calendar account as well as the webcal url? How can I make this work?