# Why Does Chromium Snap Keep Asking for Webcal Settings Change?

Tags: snap, chromium

Each time I open Google Calendar in Chromium (snap edition), I get this dialog:

[image: Snap Chromium webcal dialog]

No matter whether I press Yes or No, I get the same dialog again later. Note that I flip between two different Google accounts' calendars, which might be contributing to this problem.

How do I get this dialog to stop appearing?

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.10
- Chromium Version 88.0.4324.150 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
- snap    2.48.3+20.10
- snapd   2.48.3+20.10

Permissions:

[image: Chromium snap permissions]

Sample Flow:

- Start with Chromium closed
- Open Chromium
- Open a tab for Calendar A: get the popup
- Click Yes in the popup
- Close Chromium
- Open Chromium
- Open a tab for Calendar A: do not get the popup
- Open a tab for Calendar B: get the popup
- Click Yes in the popup
- Close Chromium
- Open Chromium
- Open a tab for Calendar B: do not get the popup
- Open a tab for Calendar A: get the popup

Comment: Could you update your question to include a screenshot of the permissions granted to Chromium? You can find them by opening "Ubuntu Software", finding Chromium, then clicking on the "Permissions" button. I wonder if this is a confinement issue ...

Comment: @Matigo: Added -- thanks!

Comment: Does this happen if you don't switch between the two account calendars?
Please try this and post feeback.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: It is definitely tied to using two Google Calendars. If I stick to one calendar, I do not repeatedly get the popup. I have edited the question with a sample set of steps and when I do/do not get the popup. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think I just found it. Go to *Settings* → *Security and Privacy* → *Site Settings* → *Additional Permissions* → *Protocol Handlers* (or copy and paste the following in the browser's address bar: `chrome://settings/handlers`) and make sure Calendar is not allowed. Alternately, if you want you can disable every site from asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant as an answer, but the features available in comments are limited enough to make it more useful to post a "comment-as-an-answer".

Actions that *could* narrow your problem

1. Check the status of your configuration as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183711/google-calendar-as-default-handler-of-webcal-protocol-for-ical-ics-files) at each point in the sequence you described, and possibly others.
2. Check if the `apt-get` version of `chromium` (package [chromium-browser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/web/chromium-browser)) behaves the same (and if not, perhaps this is an acceptable workaround for you).
3. Check whether `default-url-scheme-handler:webcal` is a setting of snap or chromium.

Comment: Thanks! Your link in #1 is nearly a decade old, and Chromium does not seem to have any relevant settings (using its search option). AFAIK, #2 no longer exists -- that's why I am using the snap. And I don't know what you mean by #3.

Comment: @CommonsWare -
Link #1) Even if it's old, the settings referred to may still exist, and they may shed some light on your problem. YMMV.
Link #2) The package does exist, apparently. Please try installing chromium-browser, as added in the answer.

Comment: "Even if it's old, the settings referred to may still exist" -- as I noted in my previous comment, they do not. "The package does exist, apparently" -- that is a transitional package to the snap. It is 47.2KB in size and mostly contains PNG files. In older versions of Ubuntu, [it *was* Chromium](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/chromium-browser), but it is not anymore.